# 'list' object has no attribute 'filter' on instance model filtering in django views

Tags: django, list, dictionary

This error is driving me crazy:

I am trying to loop through the keys of a dictionary to check if any of them is found in a list of years, so as to filter records by year in views.py, and I am getting this error. The instance model I apply the filter (e.g. `past_runnings`) is derived from chaining two models with different fields. The strange part is that the same check is executed without error with a list containing the type of sport.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
p_runnings = runnings.filter(race_id__race_starts__lte=datetime.now(), participated=True)
my_runnings = MyRace.objects.filter(runner_id=runner)
past_runnings = list(chain(p_runnings, my_runnings)) # instance from chained models

p_types = types #type of sport
p_years = list(set(r.race_id.race_starts.year if isinstance(r, Running) else r.race_starts.year for r in past_runnings))

# no error
for k, v in p_races_dict.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        if k in p_types:
            p_runnings_filtered = past_runnings.filter(race_id__type=k).filter(type=k)
            p_races_dict[k]['p_races_num'] = p_runnings_type_filtered.count() 

# 'list' object has no attribute 'filter' error
for k, v in p_races_dict.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        if k in p_years:
            p_runnings_filtered = past_runnings.filter(race_id__race_starts__year=k)
```

Comment: `past_runnings` is a `list`, so the error is to be expected. The previous loop should also break for the same reason. Is `k in p_types` ever `True`?

Comment: Yes it is. I wonder how on earth the first loop works. Has anything to do with the variables namespace?

Comment: If the code is exactly as you copied here, the loops are in the same scope, using the same list, so I don't know what you mean by variable namespaces. If the loops are not adjacent, my guess is that `past_runnings` is not a `list` when you run the first one.

Comment: It's exactly as I write it. The only omission is that 'past_runnings' is sorted after it is assigned: `past_runnings = sorted(chain(p_runnings, my_runnings), key=lambda x: x.race_id.race_starts 
        if isinstance(x, Running) else x.race_starts, reverse=True)` and so is `p_years`: `p_years = sorted(p_years, reverse=True)`

Comment: You were right. `k in p_types` was not true. That's why the code didn't crash on the 1st loop. Thank you

Comment: No problem. There had to be an explanation :)